# Is Cachable annotated method that returns HashMap is thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, thread-safety

I'm trying to understand thread safety. `@Cachable` annotation has `sync` element since 4.3 and it says in document:

> Synchronize the invocation of the underlying method if several threads
> are attempting to load a value for the same key.

So does it matter what `@Cachable` annotated method returns to reach all thread to use same cached value and not calculate it again? I mean like what if we return `HashMap<String, MyDTO>` does it do the job or I have to use ConcurrentMap to achieve it? Since `@Cachable` annotation (which I use default configuration) use `ConcurrentHashMap` and content of it will not change during process, I believe `HashMap` can be enough. Am I wrong?

Comment: The return value should be immutable or unmodifiable, as it can be shared across threads. That is unrelated to the `sync` flag, which determines if the method is invoked atomically. When false then Spring performs a lookup, calls the method if missed, and inserts the value. This could allow multiple threads to race so that the key is computed redundantly (a cache stampede). The flag instead performs this work under a lock scoped by the entry, e.g using `computeIfAbsent` from `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: "`The return value should be immutable or unmodifiable`", isn't happens-before relationship important? I couldn't get it. Let's think multiple threads trying to get data and `sync` is `true`, even the returned value is immutable it's doesn't follow happens-before since data could be created in one of any threads.

Comment: When the newly created value is published into the cache and made visible to other threads, this is done by a volatile write. Happens-before would force all preceding writes (like setting constructor fields) must also be visible. That would be true regardless of sync, which performs the work under an entry lock to avoid redundant computations. It is less risky to use an immutable, unmodifiable, or copy-on-write value to avoid accidentally mutating a non-concurrent cached value in an unsafe way. In your question `HashMap` is enough, but I might store an immutable `Map.copyOf` version instead.